# pretty breaks on secondary axis (negative values doesn't show)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do this plot (1st plot) but it doesn't show the negatives percentages on the secondary axis using `pretty_breaks()` inside `scale_y_continuous` and `sec_axis`.

`scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(breaks = pretty_breaks(), labels = label_percent()), breaks = pretty_breaks(), labels = label_dollar())`.

[image]

And I need to show like this.

[image]

## minimal example

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

test = structure(list(Año = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
                              2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
                              2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L
), Vars = c("Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", "Other.GDP.elements", "Oil.GAV.%", 
            "Non-Oil.GAV.%", "Other.GDP.elements.%", "Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", 
            "Other.GDP.elements", "Oil.GAV.%", "Non-Oil.GAV.%", "Other.GDP.elements.%", 
            "Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", "Other.GDP.elements", "Oil.GAV.%", 
            "Non-Oil.GAV.%", "Other.GDP.elements.%", "Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", 
            "Other.GDP.elements", "Oil.GAV.%", "Non-Oil.GAV.%", "Other.GDP.elements.%"
), value = c(5639977, 91442756, 7213129, 0.0987732330025509, 
             0.869107003693333, 0.0321197633041161, 6918891, 93037062, 7606055, 
             0.0913116709595953, 0.875434164471086, 0.0332541645693185, 6519993, 
             94351584, 7236432, 0.0923079337383433, 0.876825035531481, 0.0308670307301762, 
             4951333, 88365192, 5491485, -0.06, -0.35, -0.078)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                               -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


scaleFactor_t <- max(test %>% 
                     filter(Vars %in% c("Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", "Other.GDP.elements")) %>% 
                     select(value)) / max(test %>% 
                                            filter(!Vars %in% c("Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", "Other.GDP.elements")) %>% 
                                            select(value))

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = test %>% 
             filter(Vars %in% c("Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", "Other.GDP.elements")),
           aes(x = Año, y = value , fill = Vars))+
  geom_line(data = test %>% 
              filter(!Vars %in% c("Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", "Other.GDP.elements")),
            aes(x = Año, y = value*scaleFactor_t, colour = Vars), size = 1)+
  geom_point(data = test %>% 
               filter(!Vars %in% c("Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", "Other.GDP.elements")),
             aes(x = Año, y = value*scaleFactor_t, colour = Vars), size = 2)+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Miles de dólares", 
                     sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scaleFactor_t, name="Kcal per day", breaks =scales::pretty_breaks(), labels = scales::label_percent()), 
                     breaks =scales::pretty_breaks(), labels = scales::label_dollar())
```

Comment: According to the documentation you should use `breaks_extended` for continuous data.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could say the number of breaks like this `pretty_breaks(6)`. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

test = structure(list(Año = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
                              2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
                              2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L
), Vars = c("Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", "Other.GDP.elements", "Oil.GAV.%", 
            "Non-Oil.GAV.%", "Other.GDP.elements.%", "Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", 
            "Other.GDP.elements", "Oil.GAV.%", "Non-Oil.GAV.%", "Other.GDP.elements.%", 
            "Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", "Other.GDP.elements", "Oil.GAV.%", 
            "Non-Oil.GAV.%", "Other.GDP.elements.%", "Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", 
            "Other.GDP.elements", "Oil.GAV.%", "Non-Oil.GAV.%", "Other.GDP.elements.%"
), value = c(5639977, 91442756, 7213129, 0.0987732330025509, 
             0.869107003693333, 0.0321197633041161, 6918891, 93037062, 7606055, 
             0.0913116709595953, 0.875434164471086, 0.0332541645693185, 6519993, 
             94351584, 7236432, 0.0923079337383433, 0.876825035531481, 0.0308670307301762, 
             4951333, 88365192, 5491485, -0.06, -0.35, -0.078)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                               -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


scaleFactor_t <- max(test %>% 
                       filter(Vars %in% c("Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", "Other.GDP.elements")) %>% 
                       select(value)) / max(test %>% 
                                              filter(!Vars %in% c("Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", "Other.GDP.elements")) %>% 
                                              select(value))

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = test %>% 
             filter(Vars %in% c("Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", "Other.GDP.elements")),
           aes(x = Año, y = value , fill = Vars))+
  geom_line(data = test %>% 
              filter(!Vars %in% c("Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", "Other.GDP.elements")),
            aes(x = Año, y = value*scaleFactor_t, colour = Vars), size = 1)+
  geom_point(data = test %>% 
               filter(!Vars %in% c("Oil.GAV", "Non-Oil.GAV", "Other.GDP.elements")),
             aes(x = Año, y = value*scaleFactor_t, colour = Vars), size = 2)+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Miles de dólares", 
                     sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scaleFactor_t, name="Kcal per day", breaks =scales::pretty_breaks(6), labels = scales::label_percent()), 
                     breaks =scales::pretty_breaks(), labels = scales::label_dollar())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Why `6`? I've been putting different values, but the numbers `>=6`  works and are the same breaks.